# « La gauche » est utilisé pour se référer à un parti ou à tous les partis ?

Tags: sens, traduction, expressions, politique

Aujourd'hui, j'ai trouvé cette expression dans Babbel. Je pensais qu'elle se référait à plusieurs partis politiques mais Babbel la traduit par « *A left wing political party* ».

Est-ce l'usage habituel en français ou l'expression est-elle bien utilisée comme je le pense ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« [La gauche](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauche_(politique)) » désigne tous les partis dont les représentants sont traditionnellement placés à gauche dans les chambres représentatives (Assemblée nationale, Sénat, Assemblée européenne, etc.).

On peut subdiviser la gauche en "extrême gauche", "gauche", "gauche modérée" ou "centre gauche".

Comment: Je tiens à noter cependant que la gauche est aussi souvent utilisée pour le parti de gauche majoritaire pour permettre de faire un amalgame au niveau des électeurs. La gauche peut donc désigner le parti majoritaire des partis de gauche, même si ce n'est pas sa définition stricte. Tout dépend du contexte de cette phrase.

Comment: @Froggiz C'est plus ou moins ce que j'ai écris dans ma deuxième phrase, non ?

Comment: Pas vraiment, peut être me suis je mal exprimé ? Pour simplifier dans certains cas le terme "La gauche" est utilisé pour désigner le parti socialiste. A l'image des pays n'ayant que 2 partis politiques (je viens de voir au passage que bi-partiste n'était pas correct vu que ce mot n'existe pas). Ceci est beaucoup plus visible avec le terme "La droite" en France. Certains pays, et électeurs de bas niveau utilisent ces termes pour désigner le "parti majoritaire" (donc le parti socialiste actuellement). Cependant votre définition est bonne.

Comment: cet article de wikipedia donne des détails historiques, où l'on apprend que la notion de gauche (dans ces assemblées) est plutôt partie de France et s'est répandue un peu partout: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauche_%28politique%29  êtes-vous sûr que cette répartition est vraie aujourd'hui dans toutes les instances ?